# Raw query parameters in Solr are ignored

Tags: solr

I have an index which I'm querying from Solr's interface. Query parameters seem to be ignored. See for instance:

[image]

As you can see I'm querying *.* using `type=source`. Nevertheless, Solr outputs all the documents (2357). You can see from the screenshot, for example, that the first record is a `type=author`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use random arguments in the query string like that - any query should go into the `q` parameter (`q` for query), or the `fq` parameter (filter query - they're used to filter the result set without affecting scoring).

In your case the query should be `type:source` - so in the `q` field, instead of `*:*`, enter `type:source`. This means match `source` in the field named `type`.

See [The Standard Query Parser](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_7/the-standard-query-parser.html) for more information.